# Argument of type '{ pathname: string; shipment: TShipment; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

could someone help me out with an Typescript problem I'm into?

I'm experiencing the following error when running tsc in my project:

```
Argument of type '{ pathname: string; item: Item; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'item' does not exist in type 'PartialPath'.
```

The error is indicated in a line of code where I'm trying to use it's location state in a `history.push`.

The code in my project looks like that, basically:

```
[...]

interface RouterParams {
  orderId: string,
}
interface LocationState {
  item: Item,
}
interface RowProps extends RouteComponentProps<RouterParams, StaticContext, LocationState> {
  item: Item,
};

const Row = ({ row, history, match }: RowProps) => (
  <button
   onClick={
      const orderId = match.params.orderId;
      history.push({
        pathname: `/orders/${orderId}/items/${row.id}`,
        // Here is where tsc indicates the error
        item: row,
      });
   }
  >
  </button>
);

export default withRouter(Row);
```

The versions of react-router and types I'm using in my package.json are those:

```
[...]
"dependencies": {
[...]
  "react-router": "5.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
[...]
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant to pass `item` as `state` instead (2nd argument):

```
history.push(
  {
    pathname: `/orders/${orderId}/items/${row.id}`,
  },
  { item: row }
);
```

Comment: Maybe. But in the original code, I can access the given `shipment` through the location prop `location.shipment`. But when I tried to pass as a 2nd argument, like you said, I couldn't find how to access that shipment parameter. Would it be different to access in this case?

Comment: Accessing `location.shipment` is a mistake though, as that's not how `location` should be used, instead you access it through `location.state.shipment`.

Comment: At least in my case(I don't know if it's a question of versions I use or what), `location.state` comes as undefined. Any idea on what I can be my mistake?

Comment: If it comes as undefined, it means that previous component is not setting up the state. You may want to debug that first

Comment: OK, I searched for the reason of not being able to access "location.state" - the point was that I didn't know about it not being possible to use location's state when using HashRouter, as stated in the very begining of HashRouter section in docs(https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter).

Now, after replacing it w/ BrowserRouter, it works like a charm, and replacing my code w/ the one you wrote in this comment fixed the Typescript problem.
Thanks.